# Structures: Swift Playground doesn't print username

Tags: swift, struct, init

I'm a beginner at Swift and I'm currently trying to solve a problem. I have to create a `struct` and it needs to print the status of the `userRichard` to the console. The only problem here is that the print statement I used for `isActive` doesn't work for `userRichard.name`, it leaves that part blank while printing `isActive` to the console.

Why is that?

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    var email: String?
    var followers: Int
    let isActive: String
    
    init(name: String, email: String?, followers: Int, isActive: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.followers = followers
        self.isActive = isActive
        logStatus()
    
    }
    
    func logStatus() {
        print("\(userRichard.name) is \(isActive)")
    }

}

var userRichard = User(name: "Richard", email: "richard@icloud.com", followers: 0, isActive: "not active")

//prints:  is not active
```

Comment: In your constructor you're calling `logStatus()` and at that point, the `userRichard` is empty -- so it's not printing out the right value. Perhaps you meant `name` instead of `userRichard.name` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's happening here...

**Let's break down what you've got in your code:**

Everything between the outermost curly brackets here is associated with the User struct. You've set up all the properties correctly and the initialiser looks good. Ignore the logStatus() call in the initialiser for now.

Next, you have a 'logStatus' method declaration, which can apply to every instance of User that you create.

```
struct User {
let name: String
var email: String?
var followers: Int
let isActive: String

init(name: String, email: String?, followers: Int, isActive: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.followers = followers
    self.isActive = isActive
    logStatus()

}

func logStatus() {
    print("\(userRichard.name) is \(isActive)")


   }

}
```

**So what's the problem?**

I think the problem here is that you're calling the 'logStatus()' function inside the initialiser, before it has had chance to complete.

**If you restructure your code as follows, it will work:**

```
struct User {
let name: String
var email: String?
var followers: Int
let isActive: String

init(name: String, email: String?, followers: Int, isActive: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.followers = followers
    self.isActive = isActive
}

func logStatus() {
    print("\(name) is \(isActive)")
}

}

var userRichard = User(name: "Richard", email: "richard@icloud.com", followers: 0, isActive: "not active")
userRichard.logStatus()
```

I've stripped the 'userRichard' from the logStatus() function's .name bit. That means that if you call it on any instance of the User struct, it will show the corresponding name.

Next, I've called the function on the 'userRichard' instance of a User - after it has been initialised. The same approach should also work if you created a separate 'userPete' instance and so on.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for this informative answer, it really helps me a lot. Peace!